# Multidimensional Array printing in knockout with functionality over each row through click button

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, data-binding

I am able to create an array called columns which has the following structure:

```
columns = [
           {column: [1,2,3,4,5,6]},
           {column: [7,8,9,10,11,12]},
           {column: [13,14,15,16,17,18]}
          ]
```

I successfully print the array using the following code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: columns">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $data.column">
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="value: $data"</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

However I want at the end of each table row to introduce a button to be able to delete this row. I know that the button would contain a data-bind click function called removeColumn and in my view model it will be something like this:

```
self.removeColumn = function() {
    self.columns.remove(this);
}
```

I can't find a way to introduce this button correctly in my table. Other times it's created 6 times in every row and other times it doesn't apper at all. The same thing happens when I try to show the index of every column - table row so that I can count how many columns appear.

https://jsfiddle.net/qmxs87k5/4/

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or plunker? This will make it easier to trouble shoot your issues

Comment: I edited the question with the jsfiddle in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the comment syntax for knockout's foreach so you can add another `<td>` per row:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $data.column -->
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="value: $data"</td>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <td>
                <div class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteRow">Delete Row</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
     <!-- /ko -->
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Note that sometimes the nested scoping in knockout.js can be quite bothersome to work out. If the console shows an error saying can't find deleteRow of undefined or something to that nature, let me know. I can look at my knockout code to figure something out for you

Comment: Thank you. I didn;t know of this kind of syntax. By the way there seems to be a mistake in the code since I get `Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko foreach: $data.column`

Comment: It was a typo... the closing tag of the input element.